# how to fix error when i click on the top button

Tags: reactjs, antd

Go to the link below and try clicking the button

It's run in codesandbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB29a.png)

https://codesandbox.io/s/menuantd-ewelm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

I prefer to do the following, controlling the openKeys without actually modifing the values inside of it in the state, so, at render method, look at the comments in the code.

```
  render() {
    const { openKeys, collapsed } = this.state;
    // controllable openedKeys array that depends on collapsed value.
    const openedKeys = !collapsed ? openKeys : [];

    return (
      <div style={{ width: 256 }}>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={this.toggleCollapsed}
          style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}
        >
          <Icon type={this.state.collapsed ? "menu-unfold" : "menu-fold"} />
        </Button>
        <Menu
          openKeys={openedKeys} //passed the new controllable array here
          onOpenChange={this.onOpenChange}
          defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
          defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}
          mode="inline"
          theme="dark"
          inlineCollapsed={collapsed}
        >
...... rest of the code
```

================

You need to clear the `openKeys` array from your state, it states that the `sub1` sub menu opened when it's there, so, on clicking the button we should clear it to close the opened sub menus.

```
  toggleCollapsed = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
      openKeys: [],
    });
  };
```

Ofcourse, welcome to StackOverflow, it's a happily giving platform with lots of awesome devs who are willing to help with there experience.

Comment: So if I want to click on the button, it will return the open subMenu before closing.
If so, it will close all and not reopen the submenu as before. how to fix it

Comment: Consider we have hidden the menu and it collapsed, Do you want it to re-open the submenu after clicking the button again? am I following correctly?

Comment: @ChiBui, please re-check the answer, I've updated it with the proper solution.

Comment: @ChiBui I have forked your sandbox prototype and made the modifications there for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/menuantd-p874x

Comment: I'm really glad, make sure to mark the answer as Correct Answer to let others know that a solution was found.